# How to change the background color of a button?

Tags: ios, iphone

How to change the background color of a button when it is press?

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonDeleteOutlet;
```

My button has not the method: **setBackgroundColor (UIColor *) forState:(UIControlState *)**. Only **setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)**.

> No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector
>   'setBackgroundColor:forState:'

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try this

```
  (a) I think there is no method like setBackgroundColor: forState: in iOS 6 or iOS 7. So you have to put background color images using below methods

    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourRedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBlueButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 (b) Using Tint Color

    [YourButton setTintColor:[UIColor color]];
```

Comment: My button has not the method `setBackgroundColor (UIColor *) forState:(UIControlState *)`. Only `setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)`. Why?

Comment: You have to set BackGround Image inplace of background color

Comment: Here's an answer in Swift if someone stops by and is interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600980/how-do-i-set-uibutton-background-color-forstate-uicontrolstate-highlighted-in-s/30604658#30604658

Answer (score 1):

You need to set button's color for normal and highlighted state, such like

```
[yourButtonName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButtonName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: My button has not the method `setBackgroundColor (UIColor *) forState:(UIControlState *)`. Only `setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)`. Why?

Comment: But it is so. I examined all.

Comment: `No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'setBackgroundColor:forState:'`

Answer (score 0):

```
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

while it is clicked state:

```
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```