# How do I set UIButton background color forState: UIControlState.Highlighted in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, xcode6

I can set the background color for a button but I can't work out how to set the background color for  `UIControlState.Highlighted`. Is it even possible? or do I need to go down the `setBackgroundImage` path?

Comment: Check this post https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/uibutton-backgroundcolor-for-uicontrolstateselected/ Swift example at the end of the post.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

If anyone stops by, another way to go maybe more easily if it is something you need more than once... I wrote a short extension for UIButton, it works just fine:

for Swift 3

```
extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forState: forState)
    }
}
```

for Swift 4

```
extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControl.State) {
        self.clipsToBounds = true  // add this to maintain corner radius
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
            let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
        }
    }
}
```

You use it just like `setBackgroundImage`:

```
yourButton.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.white, forState: UIControl.State.highlighted)
```

Comment: This will destroy auto layout and remove corner radius.

Comment: @stephan1001 how will it do that? The image is only 1x1 so it's stretched to fit the button?

Comment: @ user4788711 just as setting a background image would. Not more, not less.

Comment: @ErikPerik Exactly. As it is a plain color and not an actual image, it is stretched flawlessly :)

Comment: in order to fix corner radius you just need to enable Clip subviews on button

Comment: Works great. Thank you. Also, for anyone new to extensions (like me), I had an error at first. I had to paste the extension code outside of the class. After that, it worked wonderfully.

Comment: For me, it was totally worth it to extend UIImage with an initializer for the color part. Then this function's body becomes simply `self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: color), forState: forState)`

Comment: to keep the functionality of the cornerRadius, just ensure that `layer.masksToBounds = true`

Comment: this code destoys title of the button. i mean that image becomes above the title. and title not shown

Comment: Why the need to use a graphicContext? ```button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: .red), for: .normal)``` works in one line

Answer (score 32):

Syntax changes to [@winterized extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604658/3659227) for **Swift 3+ syntax**

```
extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
    }}
```

Answer (score 17):

Below will be one way to go.  Two IBActions.  One to control background color when depressing a button, one on release.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) { //Touch Up Inside action
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonReleased(sender: AnyObject) { //Touch Down action
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

When you look at the autocomplete options for your button after adding a period, you can set a background color, but not for specified state.  You can only set background images.  Now of course if you are married to doing it this way instead of using the method I show above, you could load an image of the desired color as the background image using the setbackgroundImageForState property.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That solution works only in a ViewController but not in a TableViewController. The touched down action works also in TVC but only with some miliseconds delay, sothat a fast touch on screen won't change color of button. I think there's somewhere a problem with the cell in which the button is, but i'm not sure.

Comment: I ran exactly in the same problem. If I only tap the view than nothing happens because the color is already back to the old color. I could fix this problem with a little delay so that the color is switched back some milliseconds later. So the color is visible even if the user only taps shortly.

Comment: Also, I think the "Touch Down" method is risky. First, it doesn't reset the color automatically. That's easy enough, on "Touch-up Inside" just set it back to the original color. But what if the user does something abnormal, like pushes down, then decides not to continue, and drags their finger off. The color won't reset.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 4+ compatibility for the accepted answer :

```
extension UIButton {

  /// Sets the background color to use for the specified button state.
  func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {

    let minimumSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(minimumSize)

    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
      context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
      context.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: minimumSize))
    }

    let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
  }
}
```

Compatible SwiftLint and fix the bug of broken auto layout / corner radius.

Comment: Or you can change your button type to `system` instead of `custom`

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4 Version of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604658/5842521):**

```
extension UIButton {

    func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor, for state: UIControlState) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: state)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small improvement to the code, to avoid force-unwraps try doing this:

`if let currentGraphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        currentGraphicsContext.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        currentGraphicsContext.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
    }`

Plus adding `layer.masksToBounds = true` to keep the functionality of `layer.cornerRadius`

Answer (score 4):

Seems nobody here has mentioned using **Key Value Observation** yet, but it's another approach.

A reason for doing so instead of picking the other answers here is you don't need to go creating new images all the time nor be concerned with secondary effects of assigning images to buttons (e.g. cornerRadius effects).

But you'll need to create a class for the observer, who would be responsible for storing the different background colours and applying them in the `observeValue()` method.

```
public class ButtonHighlighterObserver: NSObject {

  var observedButton:UIButton? = nil

  var backgroundColor: UIColor            = UIColor.white
  var backgroundHighlightColor: UIColor   = UIColor.gray

  public override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    // Perform background color changes when highlight state change is observed
    if keyPath == "highlighted", object as? UIButton === observedButton {
        observedButton!.backgroundColor = observedButton!.isHighlighted ? self.backgroundHighlightColor : self.backgroundColor
    }
}
```

}

Then all you need to do is manage addObserver / removeObserver during operation:

```
// Add observer to button's highlighted value
button.addObserver(anObserver, forKeyPath: "highlighted", options: [.new], context: nil)
anObserver.observedButton = button

// ...

// And at deinit time, be sure you remove the observer again
anObserver.observedButton?.removeObserver(item, forKeyPath: "highlighted")
anObserver.observedButton = nil
```

Answer (score 4):

Update Swift 4

```
 extension UIButton {

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


        self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
    }
```

Event 
Button Action

Show Touch On Hightlight

Answer (score 2):

Why not?

```
@implementation UIButton (Color)

- (void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor*)color forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage.alloc initWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithColor:[CIColor colorWithCGColor:color.CGColor]]] forState:state];
}

@end
```

Comment: I tried this, but i had to crop the image, for example to width: 1, height: 1 to make it work. With the infinite extent resulting from imageWithColor it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `isHighlighted` and changed the background color when the `isHighlighted` is set.

Example: TextButton.Swift

```
import UIKit

class TextButton: UIButton {

   private var text: String = "Submit" {
       didSet{
           setText()
       }
   }

   var hightlightedColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 50/255, green: 50/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1)

   var background :UIColor = .black {
       didSet{
           self.backgroundColor = background
       }
   }

   override var isHighlighted: Bool {
       didSet {
           self.backgroundColor = self.isHighlighted ? hightlightedColor : background
       }
   }

   // MARK: - Lifecycle
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       sharedLayout()
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       sharedLayout()
   }



   // MARK: - Method
   private func setText() {
       self.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
   }

   private func sharedLayout() {
       self.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
       self.backgroundColor = self.isHighlighted ? .green : background
       self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
   }
```

}

Usages:

```
let nextBtn = TextButton()
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

In my case I needed something else, because the option with the extension and setBackgroundColor function doesn't work properly in case when we have different background button colors for dark/light mode and when we change traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle (dark/light mode). So I used custom implementation of `UIButton` class and override properties `isHighlighted` and `isEnabled` :

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.isEnabled = isEnabled
 }

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.cyan
    }
 }

override var isEnabled: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.backgroundColor = isEnabled ? UIColor.cyan : UIColor.red
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Swift 5

For those who don't want to use colored background to beat the selected state

Simply you can beat the problem by using #Selector & if statement to change the UIButton colors for each state individually easily

For Example:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //to reset the button color to its original color ( optionally )
    self.myButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.white  
}

@IBOutlet weak var myButtonOutlet: UIButton!{
    didSet{  // Button selector and image here
        self.myButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(systemName: ""), for: UIControl.State.normal)

        self.myButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark"), for: UIControl.State.selected)



        self.myButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedButton), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    }
}

@objc func tappedButton() {  // Colors selection is here
    if self.myButtonOutlet.isSelected == true {

        self.myButtonOutlet.isSelected = false
        self.myButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.white         
    } else {
        self.myButtonOutlet.isSelected = true

        self.myButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.myButtonOutlet.tintColor00 = UIColor.white

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using storyboard or xib use `@IBInspectable` by adding extension for `UIButton`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import ObjectiveC

// Declare a global var to produce a unique address as the assoc object handle
var highlightedColorHandle: UInt8 = 0

extension UIButton {

func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor, for state: UIControl.State) {
    self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(color: color), for: state)
}

@IBInspectable
var highlightedBackground: UIColor? {
    get {
        if let color = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &highlightedColorHandle) as? UIColor {
            return color
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let color = newValue {
            self.setBackgroundColor(color, for: .highlighted)
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &highlightedColorHandle, color, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        } else {
            self.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .highlighted)
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &highlightedColorHandle, nil, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Use in  Storyboard or Xib like

[image]