# UIButton doesn't get filled entirely with color when in selected state

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

`calling button.selected  = true` does not fills the entire button frame with tint color.

> Expected result

The button should be filled entirely with the tint color in selected state.

> Actual result

The tint color only filled the the area around the text in button.

[image: actual result]

How to **fill the entire button frame(area)** with the color when the button is in **selected(or any other) state**?

Comment: instead of tintColor set Button's background color

Comment: Is there any way to define this in the storyboard?

Comment: check David's answer

Comment: That doesn't explain how to get different colors for different states

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496441/creating-a-uiimage-from-a-uicolor-to-use-as-a-background-image-for-uibutton & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted

Comment: How is this a possible duplicate? @SandeepBhandari

Comment: Please read the questions carefully and let me know how is your question differrent from them. Both the question tries to change the background color of button based on button state using setBackgroundImageForState. They are returning image from color isn't that what you want ???

Comment: Okay. I'll check them. Thanks. 
Btw solution to both the questions can be same but my question is totally different. @SandeepBhandari

Comment: update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: Check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600980/how-do-i-set-uibutton-background-color-forstate-uicontrolstate-highlighted-in-s

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Instead of using system button. I ended up using custom button style and using different color and icons for different selected state of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the backgroundColor instead of tintColor.
You can set it in the Storyboard button's properties. Under "view" section.

Comment: I want different colors for different state. like transparent color for normal state & some other color for selected state

Answer (score 0):

As David already said, try changing the background color instead.

If you want to change it through storyboard, then have a look at the attached screenshot.

[image: ChangeButtonBg Screenshot]